# How to change a value in an API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetch an API in my ReactJS project. Values of this API is :

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "first_name": "ed",
    "last_name": "che",
    ...
    "showContractReview": true
}
```

I fetch it like:

```
const [user] = useFetch("/user/me");
```

I want to change `showContractReview` value as `false` when user accept a term.

```
if (accept) {
    // "showContractReview": false
  }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking - maybe you need to make an API call to update that on the server, then re-fetch the updated data, but you've told us nothing about that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the post API again to change the data in your backend because if you just change it locally then it's going to persist only till the next refresh of the app.

So, the ideal way to do it is call the API and update your state based on the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change and pass value "showContractReview" using get method unless it is provided by your backend developer to accept a value in GET method.
You might want to use POST method conditionally to send user changes to a serve/API.
I recommend you to use "axios" package for CRUD operations and interact with backend.